# Jordan Form Over a Polynomial Ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $X$ be the set of $k\times k$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $M\in X$.  The group $GL(k,\mathbb{C})$ acts on $X$ by conjugation, and according to the Jordan decomposition theorem (see e.g [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_form)) somewhere in the orbit containing $M$ is a block diagonal matrix with non-zero entries only on the diagonal and superdiagonal.

Suppose now we consider $k\times k$ matrices whose entries lie in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}, \ldots ,z_{n}]$ and we study the action by conjugation of $GL(k,\mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}, \ldots ,z_{n}])$.  Then the Jordan decomposition theorem, as formulated above, clearly no longer holds.  For example consider the matrix:

$ M=\left(
{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\\
z^{p}_{1} & 0 
\end{array}}
\right)$,

where in the above $p$ denotes a positive integer.  If $p $ is odd, then $M$ cannot be diagonalized since the ring $\mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}, \ldots ,z_{n}]$ does not contain the eigenvalues of $M$.  On the other hand, if $p$ is even we still cannot diagonalize $M$ since when $z_{1}=0 $,  $M$ is not diagonalizable.

My question is then what, if anything, remains of the Jordan decomposition in this case?  Or equivalently given a $k\times k$ matrix $M$ with entries in $\mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}, \ldots ,z_{n}]$ are there any particularly simple matrices related to $M$ via conjugation by an element of $GL(k,\mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}, \ldots ,z_{n}])$?

Comment:  Jordan decomposition no longer holds because ${\mathbb C}[z_1, \ldots ,z_n]$ is not an algebraically closed field- in fact, it's not even a field. This suggests the following (seemingly easier) question : what if we replace ${\mathbb C}[z_1, \ldots ,z_n]$ by $\mathbb Z$ ? By $\mathbb Q$ ? 

  If a reasonably simple answer exists for ${\mathbb C}[z_1, \ldots ,z_n]$, there should also be one for $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$. 

Comment: Clay, are you *sure* you want to work with GL_k over that polynomial ring?  Your example is not invertible as a polynomial matrix.  Such matrices would have to have constant (nonzero) determinant.  So maybe "GL" is the wrong type of matrices and you just want matrices with nonzero determinant (i.e., polynomial matrices that are invertible over the rational functions in several variables over C).

I think this is going to be pretty hard, even when n = 1.  The case of C[z] matrices is analogous to integral matrices, and conjugacy classes in M_n(Z) by GL_n(Z) is sneaky!

Comment: For conjugacy classes of integral matrices there is no straightforward description of what happens, but if you focus on integral matrices with a fixed *irreducible* characteristic polynomial (OK, that won't have an analogue over C[z] very often) then there is a bijection between the conjugacy classes of such matrices and ideal classes in an order in a number field.  This is a theorem of Latimer and MacDuffee. See  http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf.

Comment: Hi Keith.  Thanks for your notes.  I believe I am asking the correct question for the application I have in mind.  It is interesting that it is so difficult.  I am curious to know whether it is any easier if I restrict the size of the matrix to say 2x2 traceless matrices with polynomial entries.  Are the possible conjugacy classes by SL_2 known?  

Comment: Even 2 x 2 is tricky over the integers: all the examples in the URL from my previous comment are 2 x 2 and this case is basically tantamount to trying to understand ideal class groups of all orders in quadratic fields. Replacing conjugacy by GL_2 with SL_2 isn't going to simplify things a whole lot either, as it sort of amounts to replacing ordinary class groups by "narrow" class groups, but maybe that is too algebraic for you?  If your question has a geometric origin (line bundles?) maybe you can say something more, and I'd expect your case n = 1 to be very different from n > 1.

Comment: Keith, I don't understand your remark: the characteristic polynomial of a matrix over C[z] (or a larger polynomial ring) is a polynomial in the "spectral" variable $\lambda$ with coefficients in C[z] and it will be generically irreducible over C[z]. Of course, the "meat" of the JNF is in the non-semisimple situation. I agree that $n=1$ case is barely doable, but $n>1$ is out of reach (unless restrict to generic solutions given by the Ad-invariants).

Comment: Victor:  Yes, I confused myself by the wrong variable, so my parenthetical "OK" remark is not OK.

Clay: restricting to traceless matrices isn't going to gain you anything on this task. Conjugate matrices have the same trace, and if A and B are two n x n matrices and c is a scalar then A and B are conjugate if and only if  A - cI_n and B - cI_n are conjugate (use the same conjugating matrix in both cases).  If A and B have the same trace you can choose c to make those differences with cI_n traceless (we're in characteristic 0), so the general problem is equivalent to the traceless case.


Comment: Clay:  You say that you're pretty sure you're asking the question in the form that you would like an answer, but your 2 x 2 example in the question is *not* in GL(2,C[z]). A polynomial matrix that's invertible as a polynomial matrix must have constant determinant, and your M has determinant -z^p.  What kinds of matrices do you care about: those with nonzero determinant (hence having an inverse with rational function entries) or those with nonzero constant determinant (hence having an inverse that's also a polynomial matrix)? The example you use in your question should match your hypotheses.

Comment: Keith, I'm sorry I seem to have confused you.  My example shows a matrix with entries in C[z] which is of course not invertible.  The problem is to elucidate the orbit containing this matrix under the conjugation action by invertible matrices.  This is the same question that is answered by the Jordan decomposition for matrices with entries in C.  

Comment: You "counter-example" when p is even is wrong.  All those matrices have Jordan normal forms (ask Maple or Mathematica); for p=4 say, it is [[z^2,0],[0,z^2]] (over C[z]).  Remember that z is an indeterminate here, so that evaluation is not relevant.  If you want to ask for a _parametric_ version of the Jordan Form over the complex, that is an entirely different problem!  

Comment: Dear Jacques, it not a different problem...its the same problem.  You should beware using Mathematica for this stuff as it does not know that z is a variable.  Take p>0 to be even, and M the example matrix above. Then check using basic linear algebra that any matrix G which conjugates M to a diagonal matrix has a determinant divisible by z and hence G cannot be a GL_{2} matrix. An alternative way to see this is to use the evaluation map.  Suppose a G in GL_{2} exists then:

GMG^{-1}={{z^{p/2},0},{0,-z^{p/2}}}

Evaluate at z=0.  The right hand side is the zero matrix the left hand side is not.

Comment: What is this 'evaluate at 0' step?  z is not a variable, it is an indeterminate.  If you mean that G^{-1} (rather than G) is not in GL_{2}, then Ok, since it is in GL_{2}(C(z)) rather than C[z].  The obvious next question is: why not consider the fraction field?

Comment: Dear Jacques,  let's be clear on definitions.  A matrix is in GL_{2}(C[z]) only if its determinant is a non-zero constant.  Thus in the comment above neither G nor G^{-1} is in GL_{2}.  Second, if I have a true equation amongst polynomials f[z]=g[z] with f,g in C[z] then I can evaluate this equation at say 0 to obtain another true equation amongst complex numbers.  This should not be confusing.  Finally I do not want to consider the fraction field because that's not relevant to my research.  Part of the complication is that the set where the matrix entries are valued is a RING and not a FIELD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is "no". It is not too difficult to construct *invariants, but the *canonical forms* are hard.<sup>**a**</sup> What follows is not a full answer, but a useful way to think about the question.

The problem of classifying $k\times k$ matrices over a commutative ring $R$ up to conjugacy is equivalent to the problem of classifying all $R[\lambda]$-module structures on $R^k$, the free $R$-module of rank $k,$ up to isomorphism. Given $A\in M_k(R)$, let the variable $\lambda$ act on $R^k$ via $A$ and conversely, given an $R[\lambda]$-module structure on $R^k,$ the action of $\lambda$ is $R$-linear, hence yields a matrix. It's a good exercise to see that conjugacy of matrices $\leftrightarrow$ isomorphism of modules.
Now, when $R$ is a field, $R[\lambda]$ is a principal ideal domain, and all finitely-generated modules can be completely classified using the theory of elementary divisors.**<sup>b</sup>** However, if $R$ is even a bit more complicated, such as $\mathbb{Z}$ or $K[X]$, the question involves modules over a ring of Krull dimension $2$ or larger, and one cannot hope for an explicit easy solution (except $k=1$). Already for $n=1, R=K[x]$ we are looking at the classification of $K[x,y]$-modules.  See van der Waerden for classical treatment.

---

Footnotes

<sup>**a**</sup> For example, the characteristic polynomial and the Fitting invariants of the matrix in **<sup>b</sup>**.

**<sup>b</sup>** In the context of the conjugacy problem, you can replace a $k\times k$ matrix $A$ over $R$ modulo conjugation by $GL_k(R)$ with a $k\times k$ matrix $A-\lambda I_k$ over $R[\lambda]$ modulo left and right multiplication by $GL_k(R).$ The "elementary" part refers to the fact that when $R=K$ is a field, the general linear group is generated by elementary transformations, and  "divisors" refers to the form of the answer, where the canonical form is diagonal and $d_i$ divides the entries in rows $1$ through $i$. Neither fact is true for a more general $R.$

Comment: Although when k = 2 this question is about the classification of C[z,w]-module structures on C[z]^k  (let w act as your chosen matrix, which does commute with scaling by C[z]), there will be a polynomial over C[z] killing w by Cayley--Hamilton.  Thus you are looking at C[z,w]/(f)-module structures on C[z]^k, where f is some monic polynomial in w.   (more next)


Comment: With the analogy Z <---> C[z] in mind, considering that both are PIDs, a paper you might get something useful from is by Estes and Guralnick "Representations under ring extensions: Latimer-MacDuffee and Taussky correspondences," Adv. in Math. 54 (1984), no. 3, 302--313. (On MathSciNet, see MR0766270.)  In your example from the 2 x 2 case, the matrix [0 1; z^p 0] has char. polynomial T^2 + z^p, which is separable, and that's the kind of thing Estes and Guralnick look at. Disclaimer: I haven't looked at the paper. 

Comment: Thank you for the references, Keith! I understand what happens for matrices over $K[x] (n=1)$ when the char polynomial $f(x,\lambda)$ is irreducible and defines a non-singular (hence normal) affine curve, by the correspondence with $A=K[x,\lambda]/(f)$-modules, since $A$ is a Dedekind ring. It would be nice to see more general cases worked out in some detail. By the way, explicit matrices you quote were given by the OP, Clay Cordova. But I am not sure how much he is still interested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

"Answer" deleted due to the inability of the author to read.

Comment: If I understand Wikipedia correctly then the Smith normal form is the analogue over a PID of the usual singular value decomposition.  One considers the action:

M->GMH

Where M is a general endomorphism and G and H are invertible.  In particular H is NOT the inverse of G so this is not the action by conjugation.

Comment: Ahh I see sorry, I misread the question. I'm going to withdraw my answer.